# Two Rooks vs Queen endgame

Tags: endgame, queens, rooks

Is an endgame with Queen and King vs. two Rooks and King a win for the Queen, a win for the two Rooks, or a draw?

Answer (score 14):

Generally speaking, it's a draw. Most pawnless endgames are drawn, unless one side has a material advantage of more than a minor piece. Either side can win if there are short-term tactics. To check the outcome of a position, you can use an [online tablebase](https://syzygy-tables.info/). In particular, it's nice to view the longest wins for either side, which are (according to [this page](http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/longest-checkmates.shtml)) are

```
[FEN "k2q4/7R/8/8/8/8/8/2K3R1 w - - 0 1"]
```

([White to move](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=k2q4/7R/8/8/8/8/8/2K3R1_w_-_-_0_1), mate in 29)

and

```
[FEN "4r3/8/5Q2/8/5r2/1k6/8/1K6 w - - 0 1"]
```

([White to move](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=4r3/8/5Q2/8/5r2/1k6/8/1K6_w_-_-_0_1), mate in 49)

Comment: Thanks. So its a draw, the game will continue endlessly if either side do not commit a blunder?

Comment: In most cases, yes.

Comment: If it can take 49 moves to achieve a mate, then I wouldn't describe a failure to find that winning line as a "blunder".

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar In the last 50 moves, if no capture has happened and no pawn has been moved, then the players can claim a draw. It is not endless... In the worst case, if neither wants to claim a draw, then it will go on for some more time before a particular position would have been repeated 3 times, which in modern Chess means "draw by repetition".

Comment: @varun: Either player can claim a draw after a three-fold repetition; but if neither player wants to claim a draw, they can continue until a _five_-fold repetition is reached, at which point (under FIDE rules) the game is automatically drawn.

Comment: @TonyK Wow, I did not know that 5-fold rule, thank you. Chess.com just draws at 3 haha!

Answer (score 2):

As ever, it depends.

In general,  given adequate king shelter, the rooks have good chances when there are targets to coordinate against.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Not really. Say the ending is equal pawns and rooks vs. queen. The rooks might coordinate against any pawn to bring about a queen-and-pawn for two-rooks swap, and a (presumably) won pawn ending.  And in any position where the side with the queen can't defend a weak pawn with the king, the rooks just team up to take those, yeah?